# USB 3 hub does not work until unplugged and plugged back in

Tags: windows-7, usb-3, usb-hub

I got fed up of contorting myself to reach the back of my PC whenever I wanted to plug something in, so I bought a USB 3 hub so that it could be on my desk and I'd only have to reach over to it on my desk.

The problem is, every time I turn my computer on, it is useless for data unless I unplug it and plug it back in (It provides power at all times though)

Is there some trick to getting USB hubs to work in a way that is assumed to be logical?

**Edit:** Since installing Windows 10 this problem has gone away.

Comment: What is the model of USB hub?  Is it powered?

Comment: Plugged in directly (no hub) does the external drive show up normally after reboot?  Is this "require replug" behavior happening for multiple drives?  Does this behavior happen for a keyboard and mouse also?

Comment: No, just anything that gets plugged into the hub.   I have reached out to the manufacturers but in case it's not a problem specific to this hub, and a general setting within Windows 7 I thought the superuser community might know.

Comment: Try it with the power disconnected from the hub, does it have the same issue?

Comment: The hub gets its power from the USB port.  It doesn't have a separate power source that I can disconnect.

Comment: @MrVimes: No, this is not a general problem with all hubs.

Comment: The problem has gone away since I installed Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

6 years later, having this problem with an "insten" hub which is probably dated af.

Tried this: https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsMR/comments/8hlghs/lenovo_explorer_need_to_unplugreplug_usb_at/

"look into is USB power saving options. They'll be in your windows power plan advanced settings and possiy in BIOS. Having your USB ports go into low power mode when idle could be causing issues."

Hopefully that works